# Code runs multiple times

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Here's and example code where the code i'm executing runs multiple times.

First class:

```
public class Test2 extends JFrame {
public static int asd = 0;

private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test2 frame = new Test2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public Test2() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnShowtest = new JButton("ShowTest2");
    btnShowtest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Test1 a1 = new Test1();
            a1.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnShowtest, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
}
```

When button is pressed this one opens:

```
public class Test1 extends JFrame {
public static int ab = 1;

private JPanel contentPane;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test1 frame = new Test1();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public Test1() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnrun = new JButton("runt");
    btnrun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Test3.error();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnrun, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
}
```

When button is pressed it executes this code:

```
public class Test3 {
public static void error(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
    Test2.asd += 1;
    System.err.print(Test2.asd);
    final Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
    for (Frame f : frames){ 
        f.dispose();
        Test2 newtet = new Test2();
        newtet.setVisible(true);
    }
}
}
```

Now every time I press the buttons again it executes Test3.error(); multiple times.
For example if I press the buttons 10 times then Test3.error(); runs 10 times.

I'm guessing it's a simple fix but I can't figure it out.

Edit:

When i press the btnrun button it runs the "Test3.error()" Code, then closes all frames and creates another main frame.

When i get back to btnrun and press it again, it runs "Test3.error()" 2 times instead of once. 2 JOptionePanes and creates new mainframe twice.

If i do it again it runs "Test3.error()" 3 times and so on it keeps doing that.

What i want is for it to always run "Test3.error()" just once but for some reason it doesn't.

Another example:

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame1 frame = new Frame1();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public Frame1() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnRun = new JButton("Run");
    btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Run.run();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnRun, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

}

And the code that runs:

```
public class Run {
public static void run(){
    final Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
    for (Frame f : frames){ 
        f.dispose();
        Frame1 newtet = new Frame1();
        newtet.setVisible(true);
}
```

}
}

Same problem.

Everytime i press the run button, it executes the code as many times as i've pressed it in the past.

Press button once it diposes Frame1 and recreates Frame1. 
Press it again and it executes the code 2 times in a row.
(disposes Frame1, creates Frame1, diposes Frame1 and creates Frame1)

Comment: I'm confused, what is the question? Besides, if I press a button 10 times, I expect this button to execute 10 times.

Comment: Code should always run once, but everytime i run it again it adds another "instance"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've added an action listener here:

```
JButton btnrun = new JButton("runt");
btnrun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Test3.error();
    }
});
```

That *means* "When the button is clicked, call `Test3.error()`." Were you expecting the action listener to be removed automatically after executing once?

EDIT: Okay, I think I've worked out what's going on. This is the problem:

```
final Frame[] frames = Frame.getFrames();
for (Frame f : frames){ 
    f.dispose();
    Test2 newtet = new Test2();
    newtet.setVisible(true);
}
```

For *every* existing frame, you're disposing that frame and creating a new `Test2()`. So if you had 3 frames on the screen (a Test1, a Test2 and a Test3) when you click the button, you'll end up with three new `Test2` frames. I suspect you didn't mean to do that. Did you mean this instead?

```
for (Frame f : Frame.getFrames()){ 
    f.dispose();
}
Test2 newtet = new Test2();
newtet.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: So the actionlistener is multiplying? If so then yes.

Comment: @Jixi: No, it's not multiplying. You're pressing the button 10 times, and it's executing 10 times... once per click. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I press the button once, why does it press 10 times?

Maybe i wasn't clear enough, everytime the button is pressed new instance of first frame is created.

Now when i press the run button it executes the code once but if i already pressed it once and now press it again it executes the code twice automatically, and so on.

Comment: @Jixi: It doesn't. It runs once. From your question: "For example if I press the buttons 10 times then Test3.error(); runs 10 times." It's really unclear what you're *trying* to achieve, with three different windows interacting like this... and there are multiple buttons, which you're not describing well.

Comment: Well for some reason it does. 
And yeah, i wasn't clear enough on first post.

When i press the btnrun button it runs the "Test3.error()" Code, then closes all frames and creates another main frame.

When i get back to btnrun and press it again, it runs "Test3.error()" 2 times instead of once. 2 JOptionePanes and creates new mainframe twice.

If i do it again it runs "Test3.error()" 3 times and so on it keeps doing that.

What i want is for it to always run "Test3.error()" just once but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: @Jixi: It would really help if you'd try to come up with a shorter example (just one main method please!), make it complete (including imports), make it simpler (why have three windows?) and describe *exactly* how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jixi: See my edit - I think I've worked out what you were doing wrong.